# Past simple or past perfect with "think"

Tags: grammar

> Could you cancel my first order?  As I had thought it did not work, I made another  order for the same item. However, it did work. So I realized that I had ordered same item twice.

Shall I  use the simple past or the past perfect  for ***think***? I choose past perfect because I changed my mind: First *I had thought* and then, *I thought*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your logic, but in practice, you don't need the past perfect here.  People understand that with "thought" in the past tense, there is an implied change of heart (=change of opinion).

So -- here's something super clear that should get you the refund you need:

Could you cancel my first order, please?  Since I thought my order hadn't gone through the first time, I tried again.  However, I now realize it *did* work the first time.  In other words, I accidentally ordered the same item twice.  But I only wish to buy *one.*